# Folder scaning for images and Image resizing dependent on image width

Tags: c#, image, image-resizing

Is it posible to resize images with help of C#? I have a folder in which there are thousands of pictures. I need to make an application which would scan that folder for all images and would check their size parameters, then those which width is lower than 300px would be resized by scale to have width equal to 300px. Is it posible? And how it would look then.

Comment: Something like this maybe? http://www.dreamincode.net/code/snippet1986.htm

Comment: @Oldskool  Link not good any more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this thread. It contains samples of code which resize images http://forums.asp.net/t/1038068.aspx 
To get filenames of all files in folder  you can use

```
var startPath = @"c:\temp";
var imageFileExtensions = 
    new [] { ".jpg", ".gif", ".jpeg", ".png", ".bmp" };
var pathsToImages = 
    from filePath in Directory.EnumerateFiles(
         startPath, 
         "*.*", 
         SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    where imageFileExtensions.Contains(Path.GetExtension(filePath))
    select filePath;
```

to resize image you can use

```
 public System.Drawing.Bitmap ResizeImage(System.Drawing.Image image, int width, int height) 
    { 
        //a holder for the result 
        Bitmap result = new Bitmap(width, height); 

        //use a graphics object to draw the resized image into the bitmap 
        using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(result)) 
        { 
            //set the resize quality modes to high quality 
            graphics.CompositingQuality = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.HighQuality; 
            graphics.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic; 
            graphics.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality; 
            //draw the image into the target bitmap 
            graphics.DrawImage(image, 0, 0, result.Width, result.Height); 
        } 

        //return the resulting bitmap 
        return result; 
    }
```

Comment: Please avoid link-only answers on SO, at the very least provide a summary of the process.